# Pitfalls of wrapping callback async methods with Task async methods?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm creating a service layer for my WPF app that will wrap a web API client that uses `Action<T>` callbacks for it's asynchronous methods.  Since I'm going to need to wrap the methods anyway, I was considering making my wrapper methods of my service layer conform to the new `Task`-based async pattern of .NET 4.5, rather than expose `Action<T>` callbacks.

I don't currently have a pressing need for `Task`-based async, but I also don't have any reason that I necessarily have to stay with the callbacks and wrapping seems easy enough (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879967/best-way-to-convert-callback-based-async-method-to-awaitable-task))  Backwards compatibility isn't an issue.  That said, if there are any pitfalls to such `Action<T>` callbacks to Tasks wrapping, I'll just maintain the status quo.

Comment: just bear in mind that a you always have to catch exceptions thrown by a task befor disposing the task (i.e. try-catch around the Task.Wait methods or similar) else you will get a runtime exception in release builds!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any pitfalls with doing this, in fact it opens your application to allot more flexible scenarios. I would suggest you also look at converting some of your "call back" scenarios to a the observer pattern (see [Reactive Extensions](http://bit.ly/Q1Ni0q) project by Microsoft) which, when combined with the Task-based pattern, is so much more powerful and flexible. And of course you will be able to use your new new Task-based pattern with the new async/await-pattern in C# 5.0!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another option for "asynchronous streams" is TPL Dataflow.