# How to Force Task To Wait for Child Tasks?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have to use an API that mandates a class that implements its callback interface as a parameter to an authentication method.

```
public class CallBack : ICallBack
{
    public object Response;
    public void OnSuccess(object response)
    {
        Response = response;
    }
    public void OnException(Exception ex) { }
}
```

Authentication Call

```
public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    CallBack callback = new CallBack();
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => userService.Authenticate(username, password, callback),
            TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    return callback.Response is User ? true : false;
}
```

The problem is that `LoginAsync` finishes before the callback is invoked. I hoped that by starting the `Authenticate` call using `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent`, it would propagate down to any child tasks started in `Authenticate` but it does not.

Comment: See [Best way to convert callback based async method to awaitable task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879967/best-way-to-convert-callback-based-async-method-to-awaitable-task)

Comment: What is `callback.ReturnValue`? I do not see such property in your class

Comment: Fixed that. Should have been callback.Response

Comment: And from the code you have posted, `LoginAsync` cannot finish before calling your callback. I dont see how that is possible. The `Authenticate` method must call your callback before it is completed.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I believe `Authenticate` is starting another task or thread but I do not know for sure exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a TaskCompletionSource object to wrap your callback based async method into a awaitable task.

I assume your ICallBack is like this :

```
public interface ICallBack
{
    void OnSuccess(object response);
    void OnException(Exception ex);
}
```

So you can implement LoginAsync like this :

```
public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    ICallBack callback = new CallBackAsync(tcs);
    userService.Authenticate(username, password, callback);
    var result = await tcs.Task;
    return result is User ? true : false;
}

public class CallBackAsync : ICallBack
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> _tcs;
    public CallBackAsync(TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs)
    {
        _tcs = tcs;
    }

    public void OnSuccess(object response)
    {
        _tcs.TrySetResult(response);
    }
    public void OnException(Exception ex) {
        _tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }
}
```

For the quick explanation, when you use Task.Factory.StartNew(), the completion of the task is raised at the end of the lambda expression. But in your case this occurs before CallBack.OnSuccess call. So the result is not set.

The TaskCompletionSource class allow you to fully control when the task completion must occurs.

Comment: Why would not you explain why OP's code did not work? (Presumably OP is able to adapt code themselves from link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879967/best-way-to-convert-callback-based-async-method-to-awaitable-task you've given )

Comment: I think code samples are a better explanation than long text. And I am not enough comfortable with english to write long text.

Comment: I added a short explanation to the answer. I hope that is enough.